# Правильность склонения

Tags: склонение

Eсть предложение:

**Схема щита приборного №1 агрегатный (агрегатного) КПР №4 изображена на рисунке 6.**

Нужно ли склонять слово *агрегатный*?

Comment: Предложение дано не полностью, возможно без начала, возможно без конца. Можно увидеть его целиком?

Comment: Схема щита приборного №1 агрегатный( агрегатного) КПР №4 изображена на рисунке 6.

Comment: Что такое КПР и как он соотносится с щитом? Кто из них агрегатный: щит или КПР?

Comment: №1 агрегатный КПР №4 - это название щита

Comment: агрегатный КПР.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, связь слов здесь такая: щит (какой?) приборный агрегатный, щит (чего?) КПР №4.

Сравни: Щит приборный №6.6 насосов ЦНС. Щит приборный №2.6 агрегатный МНА1. (http://www.kanon.pro/mc/9/)

В таком случае в родительном падеже получаем: *щита приборного агрегатного*.

**Схема щита приборного №1 агрегатного КПР №4 изображена на рисунке 6.**